# Unsure of meaning of question

Tags: derivatives, classical-mechanics

A glass of water is rotating about its axis at constant angular velocity $\omega$. Let $y=f(x)$ denote the equation of the curve obtained by cutting the surface of the liquid with a plane passing through its axis of rotation.

Show that $f'(x) = \frac{\omega^2}{g}x$, where $g$ is the acceleration of free fall.

I don't understand where the plane is or what $f$ represents.

I will assume that the glass is upright with its axis of rotation passing through the origin. Is $f$ the height of the water at a cross section that is through the centre of the glass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The glass is rotating about that vertical line, and so the water bulges as such. The plane passes through as in this image. $f$ is the equation of that bulge, so yes, the height of the water at the cross section.

Comment: One more thing if you can. If $dm$ is a  point mass on the surface of the water then the component of the force towards the axis is $\omega^2x$ and the net vertical force is zero. The gradient of the reactive force has to be $\frac{g}{\omega^2x}$ so the gradient of the water is the reciprocal. Is that correct and what about the signs? Thank you for your previous answer.

Comment: Actually with the signs the gradient of the reactive force would be $\frac{g}{-\omega^2x}$ as it in the direction opposite to $x$ so the water would indeed be the negative reciprocal